# how to retrieve all the datas from clientside using jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i already fetch data from web service to client side,initially i displayed it in alert box,but now i need to show the data in jqGrid representation,pls check my code whether i need to change anything.

```
   <head id="head1" runat="server">
  <title></title>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/grid.local-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/jquery.jqgrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link href="Scripts/jqgrid/jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function()
  {
  jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
  url:"Name.asmx/Display",
    datatype:"json",
  type:'GET',
  colNames:['eid', 'ename', 'dob', 'addr', 'pincode', 'dsgid', 'salary', 'doj'],
  colModel:[
        { name: 'eid', index: 'id', width: 55, sortable: false, editable: false,     editoptions: { readonly: true, size: 10} },
        { name: 'ename', index: 'ename', width: 200, editable: false },
        { name: 'dob', index: 'dob', width: 200, editable: true },
        { name: 'addr', index: 'addr', width: 100, editable: true },
        { name: 'pincode', index: 'pincode', width: 300, editable: true },
        { name: 'type', index: 'type', width: 200, editable: true},
        { name: 'dsgid', index: 'dsgid', width: 200, editable: true },
        { name: 'salary', index: 'salary', width: 100 },
        { name: 'doj', index: 'doj', width: 100 },
   ],
       jsonReader: {
           repeatitems: false
       },
       rowNum: 10,
       rowList: [10, 20, 30],
       pager: jQuery('#gridpager'),
       sortname: 'ename',
       viewrecords: true,
       loadonce:true,
       sortorder: "asc",
       caption: "customerdetails",
  });
  });
  </script>
 </head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
    <h2>
        AJAX call test page</h2>
      <div id="jqgrid">
        <table id="grid">
        </table>
        <div id="gridpager">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: what error do u receive??

Comment: @Wahab if i run this code,it shows like "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: is the json u r returning is Valid??

Comment: @Wahab, am new to jquery and jqgrid, can u explain me clearly whether i this is crt or not,

Comment: pls do post the full error

Comment: jqGrid is **plugin of jQuery**. So `jqGrid.min.js` need jQuery. So one have to include first `jquery-1.7.2.min.js`, then `grid.locale-en.js` (do you really have `jsi18ngridlocale-en.js` or `i18n/grid.locale-en.js` ???) and then `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. Additionally jqGrid **require** jQuery UI CSS. So you should include jQuery UI CSS and then `jqgrid.css`. See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file). One can suggest some improvements in jqGrid code (`gridview:true` or usage of `loadError` for example), but it's the next step.

Comment: @Oleg, hi now i edited my code based on your suggesstion, but if i run this code,it shows "Microsift JScript runtime error:Object doesn't support this property or method" can u help me becz whether i need to change anything in my code

Comment: @Ahalya: 1) The code from the question still don't any jQuery UI CSS 2) you should remove all `,` before `]` or `}` (after `caption` and at the end of `colModel`) 3) if you have an error you should use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and write not only the description of the error, but the line number where you have the error. If you start the code in debugger (at least in Developer Tools which you start by F12) you will see the line number of the error.

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't find any error in your Grid. Guess Error Might be from some script files or from the json data u return.

```
  <link href="Scripts/jqgrid/jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /
```

is that a typo errror? Kindly check the **json** u r returning is valid using [json validator](http://jsonlint.com/). And Check the format  [Json Data retrieve](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data)